# how to set event if cursor is out of an input tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im new to jquery and i want to know how to get value of an input tag when a cursor is out/left to that input element/tag. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [**blur**](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event

```
 $(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').on('blur' , function() {
        // Your code here
    });
  });
```

[CHECK DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ykUjV/)

Comment: I know this is old. but is there a way for the JavaScript to know the id of the field that was 'blurred'?

Comment: @theB3RV yes - use ```var the_id = $(this).attr('id');```

Answer (score 5):

I think the method you're searching is [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#input-element').focusout(function() {
        // put your code here!
    });
});
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
  <input id="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
  <input type="text" value="Field 2" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
<script>

$('#target').blur(function() {
  alert('Handler for .blur() called.');
});
```